# Why is the output of my bash script not as expected?

Tags: bash, shell

I wanted to write a shell script (bash) in order to do the following:

The script is supposed to print all arguments passed when executing, that are
`(uneven **AND** greater than 66) **OR** (uneven **AND** less or equal than 88)`.

I wrote the following lines of code, hoping it would work as expected:

```
#!/bin/bash

param="$@"

for value in $param
do
  if [ $((value % 2)) -ne 0 ] && [ $((value)) -gt 66 ] || [ $((value)) -le 88 ]
  then
    echo "$value"
  fi
done
```

I do not get any errors, however, rather than filter the arguments looking for the mentioned criteria, the script prints *any* argument passed when executing.
Should I add brackets to the `if-statement` or is there anything I'm overlooking?

Thanks in advance, I'm grateful for any advice :)

*edit*: I realize the problem is rather pointless, since the condition `uneven number AND greater than 66 OR less or equal to 88` seems to include basically *any* odd number, no matter its size. I'm sorry for the confusion, I guess my prof just wanted us to practise writing shell scripts.

Thanks to @Ted Lyngmo for the advice.

```
#!/bin/bash

param=("$@")                # assign an array to param

for value in "${param[@]}"  # loop over the values in the array
do
  # use arithmetic expansion all the way for your condition:
  if (( (value % 2 != 0 && value > 66) || (value % 2 != 0 && value <= 88) ))
  then
    echo "$value"
  fi
done
```

Comment: This might help: [shellcheck.net](http://www.shellcheck.net/)

Comment: `uneven numbers AND greater than 66 OR (less or equal than) 88` Your condition lack priority and clarity. AND has greater priority than OR, but you should be explicit by using parenthesis.

Comment: I don't understand these conditions at all. "greater than 66 OR (less or equal than) 88" would seem to include *all* numbers. Numbers less than 66 match the second condition, between 66 and 88 match both, and those equal to or above 88 match the first). What are you actually trying to accomplish?

Comment: I appreciate it but don't put "thanks" in the question :-) What exactly did your prof. write in the assignment? Could it be a misunderstanding?

Comment: @TedLyngmo Why should I not put "Thanks" in the question? Is it not a custom to do so? I wanted to be polite I guess :D

Comment: @azamat I get that and you're welcome! The questions are kept here "forever" to guide others searching for help and it's good if they are kept "clean" so to speak. Thanks is best given by upvoting answers (if you have the rep. to do so) or by accepting answers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm assuming that you want `(uneven numbers AND greater than 66) OR (even numbers that are less than or equal to 88)` because of the comments made.
That is, the ranges:

- `[-∞, 66]`, if even
- `[67, 88]`
- `[89, +∞]`, if odd

Comments in the code:

```
#!/bin/bash

param=("$@")                # assign an array to param

for value in "${param[@]}"  # loop over the values in the array
do
  # use arithmetic expansion all the way for your condition:
  if (( (value % 2 != 0 && value > 66) || (value % 2 == 0 && value <= 88) ))
  then
    echo "$value"
  fi
done
```

Comment: Hello! thank you for your answer. I have not made myself clear enough as it seems. My bad. The other answer from @jared_mamrot helped me. I should have said : (*uneven* ```AND``` *greater than 66*) ```OR``` (*uneven* ```AND``` *less or equal than 88*)

Comment: Testing `&& value > 88` is redundant since the first part of the test already handles `value <= 88`

Comment: @LéaGris Indeed :-)

Comment: @azamat I see - but with those requirements, testing if it's uneven would be enough, since `> 66 OR <= 88` will always be true, right?

Comment: @azamat I updated your question to reflect what you commented here, but I interpret your acceptance of the other answer that you rather want what I've now put in this answer instead. If my assumption is correct, can you please update the question?

Comment: Still not factored, `value % 2` term is at both sides of an OR. Basically you wrote `( ( NOT A ) AND B ) OR A AND C` → `-A × B + A × C` → `A × ( -B + C )` → `value % 2 || ( NOT ( value > 66 ) && value <= 88 )` → `value % 2 || ( value <= 66 && value <= 88 )` → `value % 2 || value <= 88` and finally the cheapest first: `value <= 88 || value % 2`

Comment: @LéaGris Note that I changed my assumption about what OP _actually_ wants after having read the comment made here and also by accepting the other answer. Your suggested `value <= 88 || value % 2` will result in all numbers <= 88 being printed. The assumption I've made in my answer is that only even numbers <= 66 should be printed.

I hope OP will clarify the question.

Comment: @LéaGris I just noticed that you actually used the correct input `((NOT A) AND B) OR (A AND C)`, which is already in one of its minimal forms. An alternative minimal form could be `((NOT A) OR C) AND (A OR B)`. Your factorization seems to result in `C OR A`, which does not result in the same truth table.

Comment: @TedLyngmo your answer is ultimately the correct one. I didn't realize the other answer was checking for ```$((value % 2)) -eq 0```which is incorrect. Also, I noted you advised to store the arguments in an array rather than one single string, which seems to be the better solution! :)

Comment: @azamat I'm glad it helped, but I'm still a bit confused. :-) My answer also checks `value % 2 == 0` which doesn't currently match what you have in the question (which I put there after you said that's what you wanted). Note that my answer assumes that you want **`even`** `AND <= 88` in the second group of conditions, not uneven. If it'd been uneven, then the only condition needed would be `value % 2 != 0` and the checks against 66 and 88 could be thrown out. Do the ranges I put in the answer match your expectations?

Comment: @TedLyngmo hello again, I missed that. I updated my answer and changed the second condition to only allow for uneven numbers.